# Problem: Unable to execute the correct executable file in Unix

Tags: unix

I am encountering a really strange problem, any help is appreciated.

I have a executable file compiled and cp to a specific location. The name of this executable is "qact" There is a newly added cout statement at the first line of the main function. But when I execute the binary file in that directory, i can not see it. After a long while I accidentally find out that if I am not in that directory, I can see the outputed string when i execute it.

And later I find out that it's only when I am in that directory, the executed binary file is wrong and I will not see the string.

when I use which on that executable, no mater what directory I am in, I always get the same result and it is the correct location.

Really confused..

Comment: What's the name of the executable? Assuming it's a.out, what's the output of pwd && ./a.out. (./ is important to make sure it's not a PATH issue)

Comment: the name of this executable is "qact"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have another executable file of the same name elsewhere in your `$PATH`?  If so, it's possible that bash is executing the wrong executable because it uses a hash table to avoid extra `$PATH` lookups (see [Command Search and Execution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution)).

For example, suppose your `$PATH` is `/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin`, and you have `grep` installed in only `/usr/bin`.  When you execute `grep`, you get the obvious result:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin
$ which grep
/usr/bin/grep
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
```

Now suppose that you install a newer version of `grep` into `/opt/local/bin`, which is earlier in your `$PATH` than `/usr/bin`.  Because `which` always does the full `$PATH` lookup each time, but bash keeps a hash table, bash still thinks that the command `grep` maps to the one in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ which grep
/opt/local/bin/grep
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
$ /opt/local/bin/grep --version
GNU grep 2.6.3
```

You can use the [`type` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) to diagnose this problem.  `type` will tell you if a command is a shell builtin, an alias, a function, a keyword, or an executable file.  If the latter, it tells you the full path to the executable:

```
$ type grep
grep is hashed (/usr/bin/grep)
```

So how do you fix this?  You can use the `hash` builtin to manipulate the hash table (type `help hash` for more information).  If you just want to fix one entry (`grep` in this case), you can do `hash -d grep` to say "delete the hash table entry for `grep`", in which case the next time you execute `grep`, it will search the full `$PATH` as expected.  If you want to clear out the entire hash table (say, if you just installed a large amount of new software or you changed your `$PATH`), then use `hash -r` to empty it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When I tried "hash", it says hash table is empty. When I "type" it, it shows the correct location. Yes there are many other version of this executable. I just tried something else. PATH="<the correct path>", so that no other path exist. And it is still doing the same thing to me.

Comment: I just understand that it is after i type the command into the shell when the shell remembers the command and puts them into the hash. But it's the right path.

Comment: Just tried this. 

1. fresh env setup

2. run qact outside /apps/qfactor/server/bin --> good result, hash now has an entry

3. run qact inside /apps/qfactor/server/bin --> bad result, hash still has that entry.